Are questions that ask for standard or common terminology inappropriate as not "focused"?
My ("soft") question asking if there is a standard or common terminology for a certain flavor of directional derivatives was closed as not "focused". I checked what this means:

Needs more focus - If your question has many valid answers (but no way to determine which, if any, are correct), then it probably needs to be more focused to be successful in our format.

This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

This can often be fixed by breaking the post into multiple questions, or by focusing on a specific part of the problem.


However, the question only asks it any standard or common term exists. There is only one question. Of course, there can be multiple standard or common terms. (I do not know any, this is why I am asking.)
I suppose that any problems with my question are common to all questions that ask for a standard or common terminology. If so, are all such questions inappropriate on Math.SE?

I checked out your question. I suspect that the reviewers voting to close simply picked the best approximate reason for their decision. After all, the reason needs to be one from a given short, generic list. That is, unless the reviewer feels like elaborating a lot. Therefore the given reason is not always very descriptive of the problem.

@JyrkiLahtonen, if the reason to close must be from the list, and nothing from the list fits, this seems to mean that there is no reason to close.

Does not follow. There is a free-form reason at the end, but reviewers seldom use it. Possibly because then they feel they need to articulate the problem precisely. Possibly also because doing that will compromise their anonymity right away. More often, the close reason is somewhere between two or more of the listed motives.

The idea is, by design (of the entire SE network), that the community gets to decide what is acceptable and what is not. The exact rules are not cast in stone, and they also evolve over time. The response you see is anything but deterministic, but it tends to converge towards ... something.

Question got reopened.
